# Making log on VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I used this code to make a log on vba, and then I realize if the data already to much, it so hard to find the "New log". Is there a way to modify this code, so I could get a "New log" on the top of the data (notepad / TXT)

```
Sub WriteLogFile()

      Dim iFileNumber As Long
      Dim strData As String
      Dim strFileName  As String

      iFileNumber = FreeFile()
      strData = "Test data"            'the text written in the file
      strFileName = "C:\test.log"      ' the text file
      Open strFileName For Append Shared As #iFileNumber
      Print #iFileNumber, strData
      Close #iFileNumber
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBA can use components from the dotNet framework too. So I would strongly recommend you use a logging framework like [log4n](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/). It allows you very granular control over your logging activity.

Short of that - modify your log file name line to include the date. So you get one log file per day. Don't try to write data at the beginning of a file. That would be a performance disaster in the waiting